# How to encode a noun with modifiers like "offset direction" in GF?

Tags: gf

I doing my first steps with an GF application grammar.

I wonder how I can encode a noun with noun modifiers like "offset direction" or "income tax" in GF.

This link explains the constructions I am interested in: [noun-modifiers](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/noun-modifiers)

I tried using `mkCN : N -> NP -> CN`:

```
mkCN (mkN "offset") (mkNP (mkN "direction"))
```

which basically works, but the plural is constructed as `offsets direction` rather than `offset directions`.

I can't find other obvious constructors under [CN](https://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html#CN) or [NP](https://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html#NP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternative 1: put them into lexicon (`N`) directly

The simplest solution is to make them all into nouns from the beginning, as follows:

```hs
lin offset_direction_N = mkN "offset direction" ;
```

For English, the smart paradigms work just fine with extra fluff before the head word, because the pattern matching is really just about the end, so we get *fly~flies*, *boy~boys* etc. (This is generally not true of other languages' morphological paradigms, but if you look at their Paradigms modules, they usually have a special way of dealing with compound words. If English is the only language in your application, feel free to ignore all of this.)

### Alternative 2: create compounds at runtime

Is there a need to build these constructions on the fly from an existing lexicon that only has single entries? If so, then the RGL API doesn't have a function specifically for that.

However, there is a module called [Extend](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/master/src/abstract/Extend.gf), which has a function [`CompoundN : N -> N -> N`](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/master/src/abstract/Extend.gf#L229).

So how to use Extend? You have been using the [RGL API](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html), where all of the `mkX` opers are available when you open the Syntax and Paradigms modules. The Extend module is newer than the core RGL, so its functions are not shown in the synopsis. But you can use them just like you'd use the Syntax and Paradigms modules. Here's an example usage:

```hs
resource Test = open ParadigmsEng, ExtendEng in {

  oper
    offset_N : N = mkN "offset" ;
    direction_N : N = mkN "direction" ;

    offset_direction_N : N = CompoundN offset_N direction_N ;
}
```

For more information on the Extend module, see https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2021/02/15/rgl-api-core-extensions.html#extend.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Making this a single noun with a space is the work around I am currently using, but it feels somehow wrong  - e.g. I couldn't find documentation if having spaces in words can mess up parsing. Most classical lexer/parser constructs wouldn't like this, but I can't say I know how GF works under the hood here. Doesn't it have any lexer/parser separation?Thanks for pointing out the Extend module - which seems to be very useful for people who want to support only a small number of languages.

Comment: To give you a short answer, there's no problem with spaces in lexical categories! You can read Krasimir's thesis for more detail about the parser, https://www.cse.chalmers.se/~krasimir/phd-thesis.pdf